# Browser testing within VirtualBox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, django-testing

I've installed openSuse Server in my Virtual Box (isolated development server). In my VM I run a django project. I wrote my first test case where I would like to do a browser testing using selenium. Having current setup is it possible to open a browser on my host machine (physical computer with Ubuntu 14.04) and do testing? E.g. when I execute **self.browser.get('http://myproject.com/admin/')*** it will open a browser on my host machine?

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver

class AdminTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()
        self.display.stop()

    def test_admin_page_is_working(self):
        # Gertrude opens her web browser, and goes to the admin page
        self.browser.get('http://myproject.com/admin/')

        # She sees the familiar 'Django administration' heading
        body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
        self.assertIn('Django administrationx', body.text)

        # TODO: use the admin site to create a Poll
        self.fail('finish this test')
```